# Long table with tablenote

Tags: longtable, threeparttable

In  the following long table, I can't put table note. Any suggestion? and How I can set the whole table size?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\caption{Derived Values from applying Hill-function based method: R1%
\label{table: state table proposed net.} }\\

Parameters  & Run 1 & Run 2 & Run 3 & Run 4 & Run 5 & Run 6 & Run 7 & Run 8 & Run 9 & Run 10\\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption*{State Table for the proposed network (continued)}\\
\hline
Parameters  & Run 1 & Run 2 & Run 3 & Run 4 & Run 5 & Run 6 & Run 7 & Run 8 & Run 9 & Run 10\\ 
\hline
\endhead
   E.D.\tnote{a}  & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 %%%
F.H.\tnote{b}  & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 %%%%
 F.T.\tnote{c}  & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 %%%
 $T_{h \: \rightarrow \: o}$\tnote{d} & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $T_{g \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
$T_{o \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
$T_{g \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $T_{g \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $T_{g \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 %%%%%
 $K_{f \: \rightarrow \: o}$\tnote{e} & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{h \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{g \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{f \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{o \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{g \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{e \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{f \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{o \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{h \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{e \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{e \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{g \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{g \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $K_{g \: \dashv \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline 
 %%%%%%
 $S_{c \: \rightarrow \: h}$\tnote{f} & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
\hline
 $S_{h \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{g \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{f \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{o \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{g \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{e \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{f \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{o \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{h \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{e \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{e \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{g \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{g \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline
 $S_{g \: \dashv \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
 \hline 

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] {\footnotesize Euclidian Distance between output and target values}
\item [b] {\footnotesize Fixed Half-lives values}
\item [c] {\footnotesize Fixed regulatory parameters}
\item [d] {\footnotesize Regulatory parameters}
\item [e] {\footnotesize Half-maximal activation coefficients}
\item [f] {\footnotesize Hill coefficient}
\end{tablenotes}


\end{longtable}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `tablenote`? The caption? And you are asking two questions actually, not being connected, in my point of view

Comment: This is a long table, and I have tablenote (kind of footnote), but this doesn't produce anything. ignore second one

Comment: Ok, I did not see that `tablenotes` at the bottom... Your example does not compile

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole table size" -- its width?

Comment: yes, without those tablenotes even it goes out of the page

Comment: It didn't work in this way

Comment: You may try the package `threeparttablex`- an extension to the `longtable`-package. It has a slightly different syntax. Unfortunately, I cannot test it because I am not able to install a require packagage when I am inside the firewall at work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Sveinung has already observed in a comment, you need to load the `threeparttablex` package to get table notes along with `longtable`. Observe the use of uppercase letters in the words `ThreePartTable` and `TableNotes` as well as the use of the directive `\insertTableNotes` -- usually as the very last item before `\endlastfoot` -- to instruct LaTeX *where* to place the contents of the `TableNotes` environment.

I would further recommend you try to simplify and open up the appearance of the table by (i) getting rid of all vertical lines and all horizontal lines in the *interior* of the table and (b) using the macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule` -- instead of the basic `\hline` directive to get well-spaced horizontal lines to set off the table headers and footers.

Finally, I can't help but remark that the use of lowercase alphabetical footnote markers isn't perfect for this table. I suggest you use either numerals or symbols (such as asterisks, daggers, etc).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,a4paper]{geometry} % choose suitable margins here
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex} % for "ThreePartTable" environment
\usepackage{booktabs}        % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\begin{document}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\footnotesize
\item [a] Euclidian Distance between output and target values
\item [b] Fixed half-life values
\item [c] Fixed regulatory parameters
\item [d] Regulatory parameters
\item [e] Half-maximal activation coefficients
\item [f] Hill coefficient
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{@{} l *{10}{c} @{}}

\caption{Derived Values from applying Hill-function based method: R1} \label{table:state-table-proposed-net} \\
\toprule
Parameters & \multicolumn{10}{c@{}}{Run}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\caption*{State Table for the proposed network (continued)}\\
\toprule
Parameters & \multicolumn{10}{c@{}}{Run}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes  % tell LaTeX where to insert the contents of "TableNotes"
\endlastfoot

 E.D.\tnote{a}  & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 F.H.\tnote{b}  & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 F.T.\tnote{c}  & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $T_{h \: \rightarrow \: o}$\tnote{d} & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $T_{g \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $T_{o \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $T_{g \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $T_{g \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $T_{g \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{f \: \rightarrow \: o}$\tnote{e} & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{h \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{g \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{f \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{o \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{g \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{e \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{f \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{o \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{h \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{e \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{e \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{g \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{g \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $K_{g \: \dashv \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{c \: \rightarrow \: h}$\tnote{f} & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{h \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{g \: \rightarrow \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{f \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{o \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{g \: \rightarrow \: h}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{e \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{f \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{o \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{h \: \rightarrow \: g}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{e \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{e \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{g \: \dashv \: c}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{g \: \dashv \: r}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\

 $S_{g \: \dashv \: o}$ & 0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 &  0.124 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The footnote at end of table does not appear in my case

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to combine `longtable` and `threeparttable`. That will not work. Use the package [threeparttablex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttablex) instead. Remind the different syntax, and that the package require the `environ`-package installed.